# I want to remove special symbols, periods, hyphen, underscore & number from a string - PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

My requirement is to remove all special symbols except underscore from a string.

I am using..

```
$string = 'text-text_text+text@text(text)text&text.text*text\text/text';
$columnName = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '_', $string);
```

Output:

```
text-text_text_text_text(text)text&text.text_text_text_text
```

But its not removing periods, ampersand, brackets and dash. I felt like helpless while creating this regular expression. Please help..

Comment: `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '_', $string);`

Comment: hey thanx.. it worked..add it as an answer il mark it correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you want to remove all chars except letters, numbers and underscore simply use

`preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '_', $string);`

An expression like `[^...` in `PREG` function means, that you want to keep all following chars (so your expression results in not(!) removing ampersands, brackets a.s.o.

BTW: I ommit the underscore in the expression, because it would be replaced by a underscore again, so no need to list it in the regex

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$string = 'text-text_text+text@text(text)text&text.text*text\text/text';
$columnName = preg_replace('/[-`~!@#$%\^&*()+={}[\]\\\\|;:\'",.><?\/]/', '_', $string);
```

Output:

```
text_text_text_text_text_text_text_text_text_text_text_text
```